# How to use the Chrome Dev Tool console to check how many times a function has been invoked in a file?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I want to find out how many times a particular JavaScript function has been called in an HTML file with dev tools but couldn't figure out how and couldn't find anything through Googling, any pointer is appreciated

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use code instrumentation (or monkey patching) to track the number of times a function gets invoked, as well as many other things.

Take a simple function:

```
function foo () {
    console.log('bar');
}
```

We can patch the function to keep track of the invokation count. Instead of polluting the global scope with counts for every function that gets patched, we can keep the count on the function itself. This is possible because everything in JavaScript is an object.

```
var oldFoo = foo;

foo = function () {
    ++foo.count;
    return oldFoo.apply(this, arguments);
}

foo.count = 0;
```

Now if we invoke `foo`, we will be able to access the count at `foo.count`. The problem here is that it takes three bits of code to achieve this. The first is keeping track of the old function, the second is redefining it, and the last is setting the original count to 0.

We can improve this by creating a generic `patchMyFunc` function that takes in the function name as a string, and then modifies the actual function given the context that the patch function was run in. In global scope, the context would be `window` in a browser.

```
function patchMyFunc (funcName) {
    var context = this;
    var oldFunc = context[funcName];

    context[funcName] = function() {
        ++context[funcName].count;
        return oldFunc.apply(context, arguments)
    }

    context[funcName].count = 0;
}
```

Now we just have to invoke the patch function with our function name and we're good.

`patchMyFunc('foo');`

[image: patchMyFunc]

Answer (score 1):

A very crude method would be to initialise a global javascript variable and then within the function you wish to monitor increment the count and write it out using ***console.log***. So you'll get a list of each time the function is called and an incrementing count. Writing out to the console log form a javascript function is quite useful and I use it a lot during development to highlight activity. Just remember to disable all such calls before going to production.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yea I was wondering whether that was just kind of crude so at least that thought was verified. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but thought I would update it with a modern solution.

You can now set "Logpoints" (at least in Chrome) which are essentially "Breakpoints" that print to the Console but doesn't stop execution in the Inspector (Debug) pane. I go to the Console tab and type `var=0` and then go to Sources tab and right-click the skinny sidebar to the left of the line and select "Add logpoint..." and type in `'My Breakpoint name', ++var`. This outputs the text and an incremental value.

hth